# Need:Search of atomic cycles up to size n

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, jgrapht

Is there a better way to get all atomic cycles of size up to n then to get all simple cycles and test them?

Atomic cycles -> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_path

EDIT: Is this the same as the set of relevant cycles of size up to n?
http://www.lirmm.fr/~vismara/papers/vismara97.pdf